# usocketのストリームから読み込むことができない

Tags: common-lisp, socket

以下のソースコードは，echo関数でクライアントからのリクエストを読み込んでいます．
HTTPのヘッダまでは読み込むことができるのですが，メッセージボディを読み込むことができません．
# read-charで処理が止まっているようです．

これは，私のソースコードを書き換えることで解決できる問題なのでしょうか？
もしそうでしたら，理由を教えて頂けないでしょうか．

よろしくお願いいたします．

クライアントの表示結果

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/test -X POST -d "Message Body"
POST /test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 12
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

ソースコード

```
#!/bin/sh
#|-*- mode:lisp -*-|#
#|
exec ros -Q -- $0 "$@"
|#

(ql:quickload :usocket)


(defun echo (stream)
  (loop for input = (read-char stream nil nil)
        while input do
        (progn
          (format t "~a" input)
          (write-char input stream)
          (force-output stream))))

(defun make-server-socket (port address)
  (usocket:socket-listen address port :reuseaddress t))

(defun handler (client)
  (with-open-stream (stream (usocket:socket-stream client))
                    (echo stream)))

(defun accept (server)
  (usocket:socket-accept server))

(defun dispose (server)
  (format t "dispose server~%")
  (usocket:socket-close server))

(defun start (&key (port 8080) (address "localhost"))
  (format t "start server~%")
  (let ((server-sock (make-server-socket port address)))
    (unwind-protect
        (loop (handler (accept server-sock)))
      (dispose server-sock))))

(defun main (&rest argv)
  (declare (ignorable argv))
  (start))
```

https://gist.github.com/mocchit/2035d034931721798182

Comment: ええと、このソースコードを読む限り、これは HTTP サーバではなく、echo サーバですよね？ `telnet localhost 8080` を実行して文字列を入力すると、同じ文字列がサーバから返ってきます。少なくとも、(roswell ではなく) sbcl で実行するとその様な挙動になります。

Comment: ご認識の通りechoサーバです。 しかし、リクエストを読み込むだけならプロトコルに関わらず、サーバ側でリクエストの文字列を読み込むことができると思っています。しかし、メッセージボディが読めない為、質問しました。

Comment: あと，処理系も記述するべきでしたね．SBCL 1.2.15です．

Comment: 了解です、それでは `curl http://localhost:8080/test -X POST -d $'Message Body\n'` としてみて下さい(改行コード:`0x0a`を付加)。

Comment: メッセージボディを読み込むことができました！ありがとうございます．単純にforce-outputされていなかっただけなんですね．．．